# Starting gedit with parameters from terminal causes an error (gedit:47653): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gedit

If I run `gedit -w -s` from the terminal it gives an error:

```
(gedit:47653): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:20:04.475: g_dbus_action_group_get: assertion 'bus_name != NULL || g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name (connection) == NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

If I run `gedit` without arguments from the terminal it launches successfully.
My Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS Focal Fossa. In the previous Bionic Beaver version of Ubuntu `gedit -w -s` runs without errors.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with these combined options?

Comment: I wanted to change default text editor for the git. In many places it was shown you can change it with the followin command: git config --global core.editor "gedit -w -s". Now I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469405/216479 that the -w key is not necessary and without it the editor launches successfully

Comment: @Sergey So there you have it! You can add your comment as an answer and also mark it as the solution for your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why `-w -s` key combination gives the error, but if we launch gedit like this: `gedit -s`, it launches successfully. I found this solution here: [stackoverflow.com/a/41469405/216479](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469405/216479)